# How to search only within current page in iTerm2?

Tags: iterm

Oftentimes, in iTerm2, I'm only interested searching current page (and don't want the cursor to jump to way back in the screen history).

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks.

The default (Cmd + F) behavior seems to always search entire screen history.